# Postgresql Common Expression Table (CTE) in Function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, plpgsql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use CTE in PostgreSQL function and returning the CTE as table. But I couldn't manage to compile the function as it says `ERROR:  syntax error at end of input` in the select query. Could someone point me what I'm missing here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(name varchar) RETURNS TABLE (hours integer) AS $$
BEGIN
WITH a AS ( 
    SELECT hours FROM name_table tbl where tbl.name= name; <- giving error here
        )       
        RETURN QUERY SELECT hours FROM a;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

PS: I'm on PostgreSQL 9.6 if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CTE expression is part of the query, so it needs to come immediately after the `return query` clause, not before it. Additionally, to avoid syntax errors later on, you should select a parameter name that ins't ambiguous with the names of the columns, and fully qualify the columns you're querying:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(v_name varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (hours integer) AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY WITH a AS (
    SELECT tbl.hours 
    FROM name_table tbl
    WHERE name = v_name
    )
    SELECT a.hours FROM a;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```